# Unirgy_RapidFlow export data to remote server

Tags: magento2, error, extensions, export, server-setup

I want to export product/attribute data to remote server. it should create exported file to remote server.

I have filled the data of my server in "**[Remote Server][1]**" configuration but when I "**Run**" the profile then it throws an **[ERROR][2]**.

> User Notice: Connection closed by server in
>   /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/  SSH2.php on line 1196

I want to export(save exported file) to remote server.

Has anyone can help me a hand, please!

> [1]: https://nimb.ws/dxFvaT   [2]: https://nimb.ws/E2dnL3

Comment: anyone know about this ?

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110936/phpseclib-connection-closed-by-server

Comment: It seems not relevant to my question.